# 'webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the following error .

```
CS1061: 'webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 17:             </strong>
Line 18:         </div>
Line 19:         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 20:             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
Line 21:             <Columns>
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff (C# and ASP.NET).  I searched for a solution before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define an event handler named "[GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)" in your code-behind file, as specified in your markup.

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing access identifier. Use public access identifier in front of return type of your function.

```
public void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
}
```